# How to retrieve all the executions of a workflow by multiple status through the GitHub API?

Tags: github-actions, workflow, github-api, status

According to the [API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#list-workflow-runs) to retrieve all executions of a workflow by a status we can use this command:

```bash
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/runs?status=in_progress
```

... But is there a way to retrieve all the executions of a workflow by multiple status with one command instead to launch multiple command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this command where there are multiple status parameters in the query string:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/runs?status=in_progress&status=queued&status=requested
```

This solution doesn't return the expected result: so with this rest method you have to make a call for each status you need to retrieve information